# Ignore case when removing duplicates using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am using following command to remove duplicates from file.

```
awk -F"," '!x[$1]++' test.csv
```

How can I make it to ignore case of column 1?

I tried `awk -F"," '{IGNORECASE = 1} !x[$1]++' test.csv` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using toupper:

```
awk -F"," '!x[toupper($1)]++' test.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F"," '!x[tolower($1)]++' test.csv
```